# Python runs as a "runaway" process on MacOS when exiting Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, homebrew

Thought I would ask here before submitting a bug report.  I have just started running python3 with pandas on MacOS (Catalina) using VSCode.  I have been noticing that when exiting VSCode, python starts to eat up CPU cycles on MacOS.  I have to use the kill command.  I am unsure if this is a misconfiguration of VSCode on my part.  (I can't find anything that stands out.)  Just wondering if someone out there could walk me through some steps to check with VSCode to make sure I did not configure something incorrectly.

python 3.9.4 installed through brew package manager.
VSCode 1.55 (March 2021)
MacOS 10.15.7

- It appears that I have python 3.8.2 and python 2.7.16 installed as well, but wasn't sure about removing without losing some underlying MacOS function.

Thanks

Comment: See my post about this very topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66518708/runaway-jedi-language-task-in-vscode/66937770#66937770) FYI, it still happens to me randomly but maybe some of the suggestions there will work for you BTW I would **not** uninstall Python 2.7 on your Mac. That can have unintended consquences

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Runaway Jedi Language task in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66518708/runaway-jedi-language-task-in-vscode)

Comment: Thanks that did the trick.