# On VSCode-remote, why is python jedi language server extension is taking up excessive RAM even when application is closed?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

[image: Result of htop command].

My machine has 64GB of RAM. I use vscode-remote to access it over ssh. I note that RAM usage shoots up and remains even when I have closed the session.

In the image below are the results of the `htop` command. There are `run-jedi-language-server.py` scripts running with high RAM usage.

The vscode-remote server is running on a single repository. This screenshot was taken after I had closed the vscode session.

This prevents me from starting up other applications. What explains this, and how can I get rid of this problem?

Comment: I found a related issue which has me opt out of the jedi server protocol as a possible solution: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/15586

Comment: I think the same solutions (or workarounds) here can be applied to VS Code remote as well: [Runaway Jedi Language task in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66518708/runaway-jedi-language-task-in-vscode)